# Copying a directory into a docker image while skipping given sub directories

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to create a docker file that copies MyApp directory into the image.

```
MyApp
  -libs
  -classes
  -resources
```

Libs directory has around  50 MB and it is not frequently changing where as Classes directory is around 1 MB and it is subjected to frequent changes. To optimize the docker build, I planned to add Libs directory at the beginning of the Dockerfile and add other directories at the end of the Dockerfile. My current approach is like this

```
ADD MyApp/libs /opt/MyApp/libs
## do other operations
ADD MyApp/classes /opt/MyApp/resources
ADD MyApp/classes /opt/MyApp/classes
```

This is not a maintainable format as in future I may have some other directories in the MyApp directory to be copied into the docker image. My target is to write a docker file like this

```
ADD MyApp/libs /opt/MyApp/libs
## do other operations
ADD MyApp -exclude MyApp/libs /opt/MyApp
```

Is there a similar command to exclude some files in a directory which is copied into the docker image?

Comment: Have a look at the .dockerignore file, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: How would the `.dockerignore` file help in this case? He wants to copy the same base directory at two points in the script, once just the `lib` directory, the second time without the `lib` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I considered the method explained by @nwinkler and added few steps to make the build consistent.

Now my context directory structure is as follows

```
-Dockerfile
-MyApp
  -libs
  -classes
  -resources
-.dockerignore
-libs
```

I copied the libs directory to the outer of the MyApp directory. Added a .dockerignore file which contains following line

```
MyApp/libs/*
```

Updated the Dockerfile as this

```
ADD libs /opt/MyApp/libs
## do other operations
ADD MyApp /opt/MyApp
```

Because dockerignore file ignores MyApp/lib directory, there is no risk in over-writing libs directory I have copied earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box with the current version of Docker. Using the `.dockerignore` file will also not work, since it would always exclude the `libs` folder.

What you can do is wrapping your `docker build` in a shell script and copy the `MyApp` folder (minus the `libs` folder), and the `libs` folder into temporary directories before calling `docker build`.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -rf temp
mkdir -p temp

# Copy the whole folder
cp -r MyApp temp

# Move the libs folder up one level
mv temp/MyApp/libs temp

# Now build the Docker image
docker build ...
```

Then you could change your `Dockerfile` to copy from the `temp` directory:

```
ADD temp/libs /opt/MyApp/libs
## do other operations
ADD temp/MyApp /opt/MyApp
```

There's a risk that the second `ADD` command will remove the `/opt/MyApp/libs` folder from the image. If that happens, you might have to reverse the `ADD` commands and add the `libs` folder after everything else.

Comment: I want to add libs directory at the very beginning of the Docker file as I need to optimize the Dockerfile to generate minimum sized changes if an update of MyApp is required. I achieved the same thing with a bit different approach. I may add it as an answer.